# Call a function as soon as date is entered via Calender

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 text box `readonly` for Start Date and End Date. Date can only be entered through calender. Cannot be entered Manually. So I want to call a function as soon as date is entered via Calender in Start Date.

How Can I do it .

`onchange` and `onblur` events are not working as `calender.js` does not give any focus while inserting the date.

For IE `onchangeproperty` is working, but it is not working for Chrome and other browsers.

Can anyone help in this matter.

Comment: Look at you `calender.js` documentation about change event

Comment: better go with jQuery UI datepicker.

Comment: It's **calendar**, not **calender**. A calender is a machine used in the production of paper or cloth.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot find a reliable event - this is a hacky workaround, you can kick off a function via `setInteval` to check the value every xxx milliseconds to see if it has changed:

```
var sStartDate = document.getElementById('StartDate').value;
var iTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('StartDate').value != sStartDate) {
        clearInterval(iTimer);
        // Do here the stuff needed to do when the date changed 
    }
}, 500)
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote :) it evened my current reputation to a nice round 5700. But in addition to this service, I'd appreciate the explanation. I did say "hacky workaround *if* no reliable event is found". Oh and alternative *better* answer is also welcome.